# How to pass instance of the activity to service to form a weak reference

Tags: android, service, weak-references

In th below code, I am trying to pass instance of the activity to the GPSService and form weak reference between both contexts.
but at run time i receive the below error, which indicates that getApplicationContext() can not be casted to MainActivity

please let me know how should I pass instanceof the mainActivity to the service.

**code**:

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS_READINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GPSService gpsService = new GPSService((MainActivity) getApplicationContext());
            Intent intentStartGPSService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSService.class);
            intentStartGPSService.setAction(ACTION_START_GPS_READING);
            startService(intentStartGPSService);
        }
    });
```

**service**:

```
public GPSService(Context mainActivity) {
    this.mWeakRefToMainActivity = new WeakReference<>((MainActivity) mainActivity);
}

//causes the same error
/*public GPSService(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mWeakRefToMainActivity = new WeakReference<>((MainActivity) mainActivity);
}*/
```

**error**:

```
2019-06-15 02:01:26.848 27745-27745/com.example.gps_v10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gps_v10, PID: 27745
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.gps_v10.MainActivity
    at com.example.gps_v10.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? seems to me wrong thing to do. there is another way to communicate with activity or get ApplicationContext

Comment: also if `OnClick` is inside of `MainActvity` then just use `MainActivity.this` to get the context